# Netbeans - Restful Service with Tomcat leads to 404

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, netbeans

Didnt find a solution for this (and trying it for at least 5 hours...):

Im using Tomcat 8.0.27.0 with Jersey 2.5.1 (JAX-RS RI) and created a simple Restful-Webservice, that is working fine with Glassfish, but a try with Tomcat leads to a 404 - File not found (The requested resource is not available).

ApplicationConfig.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}

/**
 * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
 * It is automatically populated with
 * all resources defined in the project.
 * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
 */
private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(com.example.ServiceResource.class);
}}
```

ServiceResource.java

```
@Path("/service")
public class ServiceResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public ServiceResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getHtml(@PathParam("param") String message) {
         String output = "Hello " + message + "!";
         return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes("text/html")
    public void putHtml(String content) {
    }
}
```

I tried to open all kinda types possible, but expected it to work on http://localhost:8080/contextname/webresources/service .
The basic path http://localhost:8080/contextname is working.

Anyone got an idea why it is working fine with Glassfish but not with Tomcat ?  Thanks so far!

Comment: do you specify any path in the `web.xml`?

Comment: there was no web.xml so i created one with  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> but didnt work :/

Comment: Hi. Did you get this to work?

Comment: reinstalling of netbeans solved my issue...